# Variable element id in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, class, variables

```
function loadImage(a, b, c, d) {
    if (a == yes ) 
    {                       
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = 'inline';
    } 
    else if (b == yes) 
            {
           document.getElementById(d).style.display = 'inline';
            }
            else if (c == yes) 
                  {
                  document.getElementById(d).style.display = 'inline';
                  } 
                  else 
                  {
                  document.getElementById(d).style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
```

I need to use this function 10 times in my code, everytime with different a, b, c and different id. I don't know how to write variable id. Can someone help me?

```
loadImage(Blood, Unholy, FrostDK, dkclass);

loadImage(Balance, Feral, Guardian, druidclass);
```

Comment: I assume you mean `if (a == "yes")`, as you wrote it you're comparing it to a variable called `yes` which will probably be `undefined`.

Comment: as a side point, you should give your variables meaningful names.  for example, use elementId instead of d as a variable name

Comment: Also, look into `switch/case` statements. If/else's are asking for trouble (especially when they're formatted like the above!)

Comment: `d` being a string, `document.getElementById(d)` should work fine.

Comment: can you show us an example of how you call this function?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. If you could give some context, maybe it'll be easier for people help you.

Comment: All your cases are setting the same element `d` to `inline`. Is that really what you wanted to do?

Comment: loadImage(Blood, Unholy, FrostDK, dkclass);

loadImage(Balance, Feral, Guardian, druidclass);

@devlin carnate

Comment: I need rewrite this function into universal function which i can use for 10 different variations. @GustavoStraube

Comment: it's not clear why your function is not working.  we need more code.  how do you assign druidclass and dkclass?  and why are these variables called "class" when you're function is expecting an id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the parameters in an array.

```
var params = [
    { a: Blood, b: Unholy, c: FrostDK, d: dkclass },
    { a: Balance, b: Feral, c: Guardian, d: druidclass },
    ...
];
params.forEach(function(x) {
    loadImage(x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d);
});
```